# uninitialized constant DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User::BCrypt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, devise-token-auth

Using the `devise_token_auth` gem, I am making a rails-based API in which I am trying to reset my password using email.

On opening the email with reset link, I get this Error:

> uninitialized constant DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User::BCrypt

The code points to `Api::V1::Overrides::PasswordsController#edit`

```
tokens[client_id] = {
  token: BCrypt::Password.create(token),
  expiry: expiry
}.merge!(token_extras)
```

What can I do to make my reset link to go onto my reset form?

I am following [this](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/issues/481#issuecomment-244594958) for `PasswordsController` action 
Tried checking github but there no one actually has faced this sort of error and I cannot rectify it.

P.S. I am not an experienced Ruby developer.

Comment: Do you require bcrypt (`require 'bcrypt'` at the beginning of the file) in your `PasswordsController`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably just missing the `bcrypt` gem, e.g. add this in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'bcryt`
```